# Routing Testing in jasmine

Tags: jasmine

```
describe('Testing Routes', function(){
  var $route, $rootScope, $location, $httpBackend;

  beforeEach(function(){
    module('myApp');

    inject(function($injector){
      $route = $injector.get('$route');
      $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
      $location = $injector.get('$location');
      $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');

      $httpBackend.when('GET', 'js/src/template/home.html').respond('home');
    });
  })
```

I am getting two errors:
1)module is not defined
2)$rootscope is undefined